# How much weight fluctuation is normal?

Tags: weight

How much weight fluctuation is considered normal? I'm told there is such a thing as "water weight" which can explain small fluctuations -- though all mention of "water weight" I've found has been on dieting websites so I'm not sure what the scientific status of the notion is (I've asked a related question about that [here](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/is-water-weight-a-real-thing)).

How much weight fluctuation (in either direction) over what period of time is normal for an otherwise healthy individual?